# how to replace a div with other div only for screen sizes less than 567 px without any click event

Tags: html, css

//Here i have 2 divs i want div1 to be displayed on the screen before 567px but after 567px screen size i want div2 to get displayed instaed of div1

//this my div1 which should be displayed above 567px screen size

```
 <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
      <th>PARAMETERS </th>
      <th>Scio </th>
      <th>Path Lab</th>
      <th>Fitness Apps</th>
      <th>Insurance Co’s</th>
      <th>Teleconsultant App</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Annual Blood Test </td>
      <td><img src="/static/success.png"></td>
      <td><img src="/static/success.png"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><img src="/static/success.png"></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
```

//this is my div2 which i want to get displlayed instead of div but only for the screen sizes less and equal to 567px

```
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="table-cards">
    <div class= "card1">
      <div class="rows head-row">
        <div>Annual Blood Test </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows">
        <div>Scio</div>
        <div><img src="/static/success.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows">
        <div>Path Labs</div>
        <div><img src="/static/success.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows">
        <div>Fitness Apps</div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows">
        <div>Insurance Co's</div>
        <div><img src="/static/success.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rows">
      <div>Teleconsultant App</div>
      <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

please help me with this and let me know the most easier way of doing it

Comment: Please check this URL for various media queries.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: most easier way is to use media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With css you can do a media query and hide the div you want, your css will be something like this:

```
div2{ display: none }
div1{ display: block}

@media (max-width: 567px){
  div2{ display: block }
  div1{ display: none }
}
```

Comment: adding display block to the whole div1 which in my case is a "table" makes the table take half of the full width of the screen but i want the table to take up 100% width please help me with this issue???